# Remove case sensitivity (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

for the life of me I cannot find a way to remove case sensitivity from my "while" loop
here is my code, how do I make so that "Visual Studio Code", "word" and "notepad" when entered are not case sensitive

```
vastaus = "Visual Studio Code"
alt_vastaus = "word" or "notepad"


while True:
    hommeli = input("Editori:")
    if hommeli == vastaus:
         break
    elif hommeli != vastaus or alt_vastaus:
        print("ei ole hyvä")
    elif hommeli == alt_vastaus:
        print("surkea")
```

Comment: what about `hommeli = input("Editori:").lower()` to just convert the string to lower case. Then set all your other variable strings to lower case

Comment: `alt_vastaus = "word" or "notepad"` this is always "word"